# How to know when a view is the active view & then when it is no longer active?

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have a `setInterval` function that fires every 0.5 a sec under a controller of one of the views `MyView` like that:

```
app.controller('MyViewCtrl', function($scope, $http, $stateParams, $rootScope, $ionicHistory){

  setInterval(function () { 
    $scope.myFunction = function () {
       //myFunction code
     }
   }, 500);

});
```

My question is how to fire `myFunction` only when the `MyView` is the active view and stop firing it when `MyView`  is no longer the active view.

Comment: What does 'active' mean ? focus on ?

Comment: Active means the view on the screen of the user right now.

Comment: $location.path() gives you active view name. You can console it.

Comment: Great. how to use it can you give an example.

Comment: I tried `if($location.path("/myView") ) {setInterval(function () { 
    $scope.myFunction = function () {
       //myFunction code
     }
   }, 500);}`  But does not work